# How to use StringIndexer to generate numeric variables?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I was hoping to use `StringIndexer` as a means of ranking the 1000+ categories in my data set, generating an index which signifies relative frequency. I could then use this index as a numeric feature for my model. Unfortunately `StringIndex` by default stores some metadata flagging the index as categorical, forcing my model to use the index as a [category variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277576/spark-ml-categorical-features/40615508#40615508).

Is there some way of disabling this, so the index variable can be used as a numeric variable?

Edit: I am using string indexer as a stage in a ML pipeline, so a solution would need to avoid manipulating the data frame directly. Also I will be saving and loading this pipeline, so a custom data transformer may be impractical. I suspect this isn't possible as Spark is currently written.

Answer (score 5):

You can index the data and then replace the metadata. Let's say your data looks like this:

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer

val indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("raw").setOutputCol("indexed")

val df = Seq("a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c").toDF("raw")
val indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
```

We'll need a `NumericAttribute`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.NumericAttribute
```

and metadata:

```scala
val meta = NumericAttribute.defaultAttr.withName("indexed").toMetadata
```

Finally we can replace metadata using `as` method:

```scala
indexed.withColumn("indexed", $"indexed".as("indexed", meta))
```